# cy.spy() or cy.stub() is not working for new tab opened with different domain name

Tags: cypress, cypress-custom-commands

After clicking an image in my application a new tab is getting opened with different domain URL, but I am getting below error

Code -

```
cy.window().then((win) => {
   cy.spy(win, 'open').as('@redirect')
});

cy.get('webElement').click();
cy.get('@redirect').should('be.called')

Note: 
1. webElement clicked is 'img' not anchor and it does not have any 'href' and 'target' attribute.
2. Same code is working fine when new tab url is of same domain.
```

[DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vjODh.png)
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HPip.png)

Answer (score 0):

The alias should not be named @redirect but redirect:

```
cy.spy(win, 'open').as('@redirect')
```

Correct:

```
cy.spy(win, 'open').as('redirect')
```

You are asserting it correctly.

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/as#DOM-element